# How to determine whether the object is a value type

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, portable-class-library

I could use Type.IsValueType to figure this out in a straightforward way in .net 4.5, but when I create universal apps using the portable library, it doesn't have any equivalent method to find if the type is value or not.

Is there any other trick to finding this?

Comment: This says it is supported for a portable library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do you want to write a dll to be used in other project?

Comment: It says its supported but I cannot find the property in the Type class of System namespace when I write an universal app:

Error 1 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'isValueType' and no extension method 'isValueType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @sargeMonkey: It is `IsValueType` with uppercase i

Comment: What's wrong with `IsValueType`?

Comment: IsValueType is not available with Windows Runtime 8.1 - so I cannot use it in an universal app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround I found is:

typeof(ValueType).IsAssignableFrom(type)

Comment: Does this work? I thought everything derived from `System.Object`.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a mistake in the copy/paste :) Its fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

Try `type.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType`.  Also make sure you have a using statement for System.Reflection, so the `GetTypeInfo()` extension method is available.

Comment: Its not available in windows 8.1 runtime

Comment: @sargeMonkey What makes you think it's not there?  I created a new blank universal app, added a class to the shared project, and was able to access `typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().IsValueType` after adding a `using System.Reflection;` statement.

Comment: Try adding a .net 4 library project into the solution and see if the above code works...I should have mentioned earlier, that is where I am stuck

Comment: @sargeMonkey In a .NET 4 library project, `IsValueType` is directly available on Type (ie you don't need to call `GetTypeInfo`).  But you can't reference a .NET 4 project from a Windows 8.1 app.  Are you trying to link the same file into both projects?  Or are you using a PCL targeting .NET 4?  Or what's going on?

Comment: Either way causes this problem. You can add a PCL targeting windows 8.1, and add the same code there, and it can cause this issue. I'm writing a library with a shared PCL targeting multiple platforms. .net 4 win 8.1 runtime target does not give me a type.IsValueType or type.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType